# SharePoint 2016 : REST API issue

Tags: list, lookup-column, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api, cross-site

I have one list which contains cross-site lookup field. I need to filter with this field using REST API. Below is my URL

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists(guid'" + listId + "')/items/?$select=Created,Title,Project/Id&$expand=Project/Id&$filter=Project/Id eq 3"
```

It gives below error

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPExceptionThe field or property 'Project' does not exist.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you can't expand the column 'Project' as its not on the same site.

REST API's `expand` supports only for same site list columns.

See [this](http://kristofeschberger.com/sp2013-rest-api-doesnt-support-cross-site-lookups/) for more reference.